# How to write a c# program to add descending numbers to xml,json and text file format using factory pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line, command-line-arguments, factory-pattern

I wanted to write a c# program which takes comma seperated numbers as one input and file format as second input
So
Enter Numbers : 5,6,7,8,10,11
Enter File Format : JSON

after getting the input the numbers should be sorted in descending order and based on entered file format it should add descended numbers into that format and download the file.This i need using factory pattern.

I have written the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Comma Seperated Values");  
    string commasepratedstring = Console.ReadLine();  
               Console.WriteLine("Enter File Format");  
    string fileformat = Console.ReadLine();  
 

  string Output = String.Join(",", commasepratedstring
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .OrderBy(x => x));


    string Text = ""; 
    switch(fileformat)
    {
        case "XML":
        Text = "This is XML";
        break;
        case "Text":
        Text = "This is Text";
         break;
        case "JSON":
         Text = "This is JSON";
         break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Output);
     Console.WriteLine(Text);
            Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I am able sort the numbers but i want to put the out put in respective formats like XML should be parsed as xml in xml file format and JSON should be in JSON format. Thanks

Comment: What is the requirement. Who is the consumer of this method. The Web API have this feature which automatically send the response in xml or json depending on the request. [One of the examples is](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/request-response-data-formats-in-web-api)

Comment: Use the [Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) to sort in descending order. You will find what you need in the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=net-6.0) and the [System.Json Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).